# Rails bundle install hanging in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

Here is a screenshot of

bundle install --verbose

This is where is just hangs permanently. It works fine on another MacBook Pro, but not one of the Imacs so it must be a version or something possibly? I don't know where to start.

[image]

and here is the gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'thin', '->1.5.1'
gem "rails", "~> 3.2"
gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.4"
gem "simple_form", "~> 2.0.2"
gem "devise", "~> 2.2.4"
gem 'devise-encryptable'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem "draper", "0.18"
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'going_postal'
gem "gmaps4rails", "~> 1.5.6"
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem "aws-sdk"
gem "chronic", "~> 0.8.0"
gem 'faker'
gem 'postmark-mitt'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem "pg", "~> 0.15.1"
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'activerecord-reset-pk-sequence'
gem 'dropzonejs-rails', '~> 0.4.1'
gem 'integer-obfuscator'
gem 'time_diff', "~> 0.3.0"
gem "sanitize", "~> 2.0.3"
gem 'certified' # for ssl error on facebook redirect
gem 'realex'
gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'


group :production do
    ruby '1.9.3'
    gem 'heroku-deflater'
    gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end

group :assets, :staging do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
    gem "capybara", "~> 2.1.0"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 0.7.2"
  gem "launchy", "~> 2.1.0"
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.10.1"
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 3.2.0" 
  gem "guard-rspec", "~> 0.7.0"
  gem "spork"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

group :development do

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to try.

1. Remove your `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` again.
2. Put the `rails` gem first instead of `thin`.

Comment: Thanks for this, but nothing happens. Its just the same.

Comment: Is there a place where I can pull in this code to test it out? Might be able to help you better that way. :)